# What is the cross-platform way to handle compound literals in C++?

Tags: c++

What is the way to use compound literals in C++ in a cross-platform way? I know it's an extension and not 'official' C++, but there must be a way, right?

My struct is:

```
struct v2 {
    int x, y; 
};
```

I want to:

1. change all struct values in one go when a struct is already initialised.
2. create an object inline, so I can pass a struct directly as an argument to a function

This works, but is very cumbersome:

```
v2 position = {0,1};
DoSomething(position);
```

```
DoSomething( v2 {0,1} );
```

Works in MSVC, but gives a syntax error in Clang: `error: expected ')'`

```
DoSomething( (v2) {0,1} );
```

Works in Clang, but gives a syntax error in MSVC cl.exe: `error C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax`

This works in MSVC, but is a syntax error in Clang `error: expected expression`

```
DoSomething( {0,1} );
```

Also I cannot change the value later on:

```
position = v2 {1,1};
```

Works in MSVC, but not in Clang: `error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`

```
position = (v2) {1,1};
```

Works in Clang, but not in MSVC: `error C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax`

Anyone with the answer?

Comment: `DoSomething({0, 1});`?

Comment: can you post a [mcve]? When you are talking about compiler errors, you should include them in the question. Compound literals is a C feature. Are you sure you really need them in C++?

Comment: " but there must be a way, right?" no. If it isnt standard C++, but only offered as extension by some compilers then it isnt portable by definition

Comment: @idclev463035818 But direct-list-initialisation (which is what the “MSVC” syntax is) *is* standard C++. And clang obviously supports it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I just saw compound literals for the first time. Are you saying that direct-list-initialisation is the same as compound literals or are you saying that in C++ you can use direct-list initialization instead. If it is the later, thats more or less what I tried to say

Comment: @idclev463035818 The latter, yes.

Comment: please clarify if you need to use compound literals or if you merely need to create an instance inline and compound literals is what you think is the solution.

Comment: I want to create an object inline yes. Also I want to be able to edit an object later on in one go. I don't want to use any (constructor) function to create the v2, so no `V2(1,1)`. Updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless if `v2` is defined like this (with all public member variables):

```
struct v2 {
    int x, y; 
};
```

or like this (with a converting constructor):

```
class v2 {
public:
    v2(int X, int Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}

private:
     int x, y; 
};
```

... you can use it like this **if you use C++11 or later** (`clang++ -std=c++11 ...`):

```
void DoSomething(const v2& v) {
    //... do something ...
}

int main() {
    DoSomething({0, 1});

    v2 position = {1, 2};
    DoSomething(position);
    
    position = {2, 3};
    DoSomething(position);
}
```

Comment: No, not for Clang: `DoSomething({0, 1});` gives a syntax error in Clang: `error: expected expression`. Also `position = {2, 3};` does not work: gives the same syntax error: `error: expected expression`. I've updated my original post.

Comment: @Eddie's Actually [it works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Tx522O0phnZfqItf).

Comment: I can see it working on that site with the default Clang versions, but it doesn't work here with default Clang... I use Apple clang version 11.0.3. If I compile with the same line as this site, I get the aformentioned syntax errors `error: expected expression`.

Comment: @Eddie's See my updated answer - I think your compiler defaults to an ancient version of C++. Unless you are maintaining a really old project - there is absolutely **no reason** to use C++03 or C++98.

Comment: Yes, thank you, using `-std=c++11` does solve the compatibility problems between Clang and MSVC for the inlining objects/compound literal problem. Curious why it doesn't work with default Clang here, but does on the link @Constructor posted.

Comment: @Eddie's I guess you have a very very old version of `clang++` or that the Apple distribution is configured to default to C++98 or C++03 for some reason. What does `clang++ --version` say?

Comment: `Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)`. It looks like e.g. `v2 {1,1}` is a c++11 feature, so it makes sense to specify Clang to use this. MSVC seems to not care about any c++ versions and just cherry picks features from the standard?

Comment: @Eddie's That's a very recent version of `clang++`  but it seems `clang++` uses C++98 by default (I didn't even know that since I _always_ specify the version I want).  Recent MSVC versions can't even be set in C++11 mode if I'm correct. I think C++14 is the oldest it supports.